# How to use setUserVisibleHint in Fragment on Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment

In my application i have `BottomNavBar` and i want show `fragments` when click on items of this `BottomNavBar`! 
For set this `fragments` with `BottomNavBar` i used [`NavigationGraph`](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-design-graph) component!

I want use **`setUserVisibleHint`** method for one of this `fragment`, but when show this `fragment` not call **`setUserVisibleHint`** !

**My Activity codes** for set `fragments` to `BottomNavBar` items :

```
class HomeActivity : BaseActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    setupNavigation()

    }

        private fun setupNavigation() {
        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.homePage_fragmentNavHost)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(homePage_bottomNavBar, navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.homePage_fragmentNavHost).navigateUp()
}
```

**My Fragment codes :**

```
class HomeDashboardFragment : Fragment(){

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_dashboard, container, false)
    }

    override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            Handler().postDelayed({ requireContext().toast("Show") }, 500)
        }
    }
}
```

Why not work `setUserVisibleHint` into `fragment` ?

Comment: Don't worry, `setUserVisibleHint` will be deprecated in the next AndroidX Fragment release.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce why? What should we use instead of this ?

Comment: `FragmentTransaction.setMaxLifecycle`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, how to use it? can you send to me code? i need your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you put this code you know about fragment life cycle

```
 override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
           // post your code
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        userVisibleHint = true
    }
```

Comment: thanks my friend, it's work to me. but why deprecated this  `setUserVisibleHint` ?

Comment: NO...it's not deprecated. its still working.. welcome... happy coding...

Comment: It will be deprecated quite soon, actually. The next AndroidX Fragment release deprecates `setUserVisibleHint`.

Comment: Now its deprecated

Comment: Why is this deprecated?!  I've read the description of setMaxLifeCycle twice and still have no idea how it would replace setUserVisibleHint-- which I use to hide the soft keyboard and take other actions (trigger animations for example) in a ViewPager when a fragment comes fully into view.

Answer (score 36):

As setUserVisibleHint(boolean aBoolean) is now deprecated, for those who still want to know when a fragment is visible you can still use

```
 public FragmentTransaction setMaxLifecycle(Fragment fragment, Lifecycle.State state)
```

either indirectly with a FragmentPagerAdapter (or FragmentStatePagerAdapter)
just by using the new Constructor

```
MyFPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm ,FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
       //...
}
```

note that 
FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT allows the adapter to use setMaxLifecycle internally (through setPrimaryItem) instead of setUserVisibleHint.
Hence in your fragment's implementation you won't anymore need to use

```
setUserVisibleHint(boolean aBoolean)
```

but instead, onResume() cause now onResume() will be called only for the visible fragment. the rest ones will still be able to reach onCreateView().

The direct way is by using setMaxLifeCycle with FragmentTransaction when adding or switching fragment, where then

```
setMaxLifecycle(fragment, Lifecycle.State.STARTED);
```

is equivalent

```
setUserVisibleHint(false);
```

and

```
setMaxLifecycle(fragment, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
```

equivalent to

```
setUserVisibleHint(true);
```

then again listen with Fragment's onResume() callback

Comment: how if applying in ViewPager2?

Comment: ```but instead, onResume() cause now onResume() will be called only for the visible fragment``` solved my problem thanks

Comment: What about normal onResume when i came back from background?

Answer (score 3):

> After AndroidX **setUserVisibleHint** is deprecated as a replacement
> we can use the **setMenuVisibility** Method.

```
  override fun setMenuVisibility(menuVisible: Boolean) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BottomSheetBehavior https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior for this type of implementation. You can user BottomSheetDialogFragment as well.

To set specific behavior use this code  e.g.

```
bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(300);
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation), this may not be the best way to achieve the behavior you desire. Navigation has an [OnDestinationChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener.html) Interface that receives a callback whenever [NavController.getCurrentDestination](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController.html#getCurrentDestination()) is called.

Luckily you're using Kotlin and in HomeActivity you may be able to get away with something like:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
    Handler().postDelayed({ requireContext().toast("Show") }, 500)
}
```

And you should get the desired result.

If you are new to Navigation I would recommend [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) codelab. It goes through some of the basics and can help get you started. For some of the more advanced concepts, you can checkout the [NavigationAdvancedSample](https://github.com/jbw0033/android-architecture-components/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) on Github.

If you would like to directly use Fragments anyway, it would probably be more reliable to use the lifecycle methods (onStart) over setUserVisibleHint().

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onPrimaryNavigationFragmentChanged(isPrimaryNavigationFragment: Boolean) {
        super.onPrimaryNavigationFragmentChanged(isPrimaryNavigationFragment)
        if (isPrimaryNavigationFragment) {
            // Your fragment is shown
        } else {
            // Your fragment is hidden
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't simply post code. Add some context to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser){
        if (NetworkUtils.isConnected(getActivity())) {
            callYourApi();
        } 
    }
}
```